# Why does my logistic regression is predicting either for 0 or for 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

When i run my code it generate theta for 0 or 1 alternatively.
It's like
First time code run: predicts only 0
Second time code run: predicts only 1

```py
class logistic_regression():        
    def H(self, X, theta):
        z = np.dot( X, theta)
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

    def cost_function(self, X, theta, y):
        h = self.H(X , theta)
        return (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()

    def gradient_descent(self, X, y, theta, iters, alpha):
        self.cost = np.zeros(iters)
        h = self.H(X , theta)
        gradient = np.dot( X.T, ( h - y )) / y.shape[0]
        for i in range(iters):
            theta -= alpha * gradient
            self.cost[i] = self.cost_function(X, theta, y)
        return theta, cost

    def predictions(self, X, theta, threshold=0.5):
        return self.H(X, theta) >= threshold

#applying the code

lr = logistic_regression()
new_theta, cost = lr.gradient_descent(X, y, theta, iters, alpha)

result = lr.H(X, new_theta)

print(new_theta)
print('\n')
print(result)

#output 1st time
[  -2.6197013    -8.62233216 -107.01170844]


[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]

#output 2nd time
[  8.55507128 139.32508563 129.80393891]


[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
```

There is no error message but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Check if the data is imbalanced. The propoetion of 1's is more in train data, the results all will be 1.

Comment: But that still doesn't make sense of getting different result

Comment: when you say #output 1st time, it's the raw output of the logistic regression? If so, something is really wrong with the code, because the logit function (sigmoid) outputs values between 0 and 1 (which are interpreted as probabilities)

Comment: Yup it is a raw output. But i don't know what is wrong in the code

Comment: BTW the the ratio of 1 and 0 is                                                                                
0:-    110316
1:-    31877

Comment: Check the results without doing gradient_descent in final stage. Lets see

Comment: you mean with the orignal theta values

Comment: @HRSharma Yes, Original values

Comment: it gives only 1 and theta values were 0